# Conditional Output React Native

Tags: reactjs, native

I'm a React Native noob, and cannot figure out how to get this working:

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'

const Block = () => {
return (<Text>1</Text>);
}

const Noti = <Block />;

const Result = () => {
  
  let content

  if (Noti == 1) {
    content = <Text style={{ fontSize: 24, color: 'red' }}>One!</Text>
  } else if (Noti == 2) {
    content = <Text style={{ fontSize: 24, color: 'gray' }}>Two!!</Text>
  } else if (Noti == 3) {
    content = <Text style={{ fontSize: 24, color: 'gray' }}>Three!!!</Text>
  }

  return <View style={{ padding: 24 }}>{content}</View>
}

export default Result;
```

`const Block` would be an imported component. That imported component will be a number from 1 - 3.

**IF** that number is 1, content = “One!”. **IF** that number is 2, content = “Two!”… and so forth.

The job of `const Noti` is to simply read that number and pass it on to the conditionals in `const Result`.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!